# How to bind two const data to form a react table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have two const data and I want to build a react table using those two data.
In state, I have defined countBySimilarWords as

```
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.state = {
        countBySimilarWords: {}
    }
}
```

and I have imported some json file. In render, I am populating the logic for count like this

```
const { countBySimilarWords } = this.state
const data = Object.keys(countBySimilarWords).map((key) => {
    countBySimilarWords[key]["word"] = key
    const wordMeaning = totalword.map(( totalword) => {
        if (totalword.word === key) {
            totalword.synonym.map((eachCase) => { 
                console.log("each synonym " + eachCase.another)
            }) 
        }

        return totalword
    }) 
    return countBySimilarWords[key]
})
```

Now I am getting all the response properly  but I want to display json data as well as count in a reacttable But unable to do that. Now I am doing that.

```
<ReactTable
    className='-striped -highlight'
    filterable
    columns={this.getColumns()}
    data={table}
/>
```

I am getting all count related data but not json data. Please advise!!

Comment: please attach your sample json data, final data structure.

Comment: I think even you setup the `columns` wrong, the real magic for things to show up is in `data`. So print out `data`, it needs to be an `array`.

Comment: Add both your sample data and sample output in the question for better visualization.